# Error import type in dépendance Javascript, Typescript, ReactJS and Navigation Stack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native-navigation, webpack-encore

Hello i use Webpack encore and in my project, i install typescript.

On start the project no problem.
Now i install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack

They are in this dépendance

import type or import typeof

When i use Yarn watch i have this error :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

If you know this problem ?

Cordialy

[image]

Comment: You can't use `import type`  in JavaScript file

Comment: It's a dépendance, it's not my App.tsx

Comment: The dépendance is react-native

Comment: Could you show how you import these libraries?

Comment: On top of file App.tsx

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

Comment: And in render i have error when i write this row : const ModalStack = createStackNavigator();